# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text' with input id

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

```
url = 'https://www.amazon.ca/Powerextra-Replacement-Battery-Compatible-NP-FZ100/dp/B07PQQQ82K/ref=bmx_4?pd_rd_w=TNcoX&pf_rd_p=d9347c84-a27a-4c22-b959-7bb71382273b&pf_rd_r=E7RKN5D6HSM4TFZQJCGT&pd_rd_r=e8bff283-bc96-4b77-b31a-f413b4d62e40&pd_rd_wg=wje3Z&pd_rd_i=B07PQQQ82K&psc=1'
headers = 'headers = { "user-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'}'
page = requests.get(url, headers= headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")

title = soup.find('input', {'id': 'mbb-offeringID-1'}).get_text()
print(title)
```

I also tried:

```
title = soup.find('input', {'id': 'mbb-offeringID-1'}).get('value')
print(title)
```

Then I  tried if it works in general with a "span id" and it gave the same error

```
title = soup.find(id = "productTitle").get_text()
```

Comment: Looks like that ID is not in the HTML that is retrieved by `requests`. Are you sure that it is not loaded afterwards using Javascript? `print('mbb-offeringID-1' in soup) # False`

Comment: It printed false

Comment: Yes, which means the element you're looking for is not present from your initial `requests.get()` call. This may mean that Amazon are including that HTML content _after_ the page has initially loaded through Javascript which would mean it is not possible to scrape the content using this method. You would have to emulate a browser that runs Javascript using a framework such as Selenium.

Comment: thank you for the reply. Selenium is pretty good, it's just not convient to switch proxies with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5"` HTTP header for correct response from the server:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.amazon.ca/Powerextra-Replacement-Battery-Compatible-NP-FZ100/dp/B07PQQQ82K/ref=bmx_4?pd_rd_w=TNcoX&pf_rd_p=d9347c84-a27a-4c22-b959-7bb71382273b&pf_rd_r=E7RKN5D6HSM4TFZQJCGT&pd_rd_r=e8bff283-bc96-4b77-b31a-f413b4d62e40&pd_rd_wg=wje3Z&pd_rd_i=B07PQQQ82K&psc=1"
headers = headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")

title = (
    soup.find("input", {"id": "mbb-offeringID-1"})
    .find_next("span")
    .get_text(strip=True, separator=" ")
)
print(title)
```

Prints:

```
Asurion 3-Year Protection Plan for $14.99
```

Comment: Hi, Again. I tried to pass a proxy within request.get before soup = ......  , and it gives me the same error again.

Comment: @ShiO Make sure that you've received normal page and not Captcha page. With proxy sites this is pretty common.

Comment: Thanks again, it seems the proxy is directing me to the captcha page. Weird, it's residential proxies and I barely use them.